# dependency problems - leaving unconfigured

Tags: linux, git, ubuntu, sudo, apt

This is what I get when I tried to install git in Ubuntu 18.04. I may have asked a repeated question but I am not getting any solution.

```
kcn@kcn-UBUNTU:~$ sudo apt-get install git
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
git is already the newest version (1:2.17.1-1ubuntu0.3).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
3 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/7,732 B of archives.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y

dpkg: error processing package libavahi-glib1:amd64 (--configure):
 package is in a very bad inconsistent state; you should
 reinstall it before attempting configuration

dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of geoclue-2.0:
 geoclue-2.0 depends on libavahi-glib1 (>= 0.6.16); however:
  Package libavahi-glib1:amd64 is not configured yet.

No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                                                                                          dpkg: error processing package geoclue-2.0 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured

dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libgeoclue-2-0:amd64:
 libgeoclue-2-0:amd64 depends on geoclue-2.0 (= 2.4.7-1ubuntu1); however:
  Package geoclue-2.0 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libgeoclue-2-0:amd64 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured

No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.


Errors were encountered while processing:
 libavahi-glib1:amd64
 geoclue-2.0
 libgeoclue-2-0:amd64
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I tried to do the following:

```
kcn@kcn-UBUNTU:~$ sudo apt-get install git
```

> [sudo] password for kcn:
>
> E: dpkg was interrupted, you must manually run 'sudo dpkg --configure
>   -a' to correct the problem.

So I typed

```
kcn@kcn-UBUNTU:~$ sudo dpkg --configure -a
................

................

dpkg: error processing package libavahi-glib1:amd64 (--configure):
 package is in a very bad inconsistent state; you should
 reinstall it before attempting configuration
```

Comment: `sudo dpkg --configure <first dependency package with error>`
solved my problem.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Try this out:

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
sudo apt-get -f install
sudo apt install libavahi-glib1 --reinstall
```

---

#### **`sudo dpkg --configure -a`**

Instruct dpkg to "fix" itself

#### **`sudo apt-get -f install`**

This will instruct apt-get to correct dependencies and continue to configure your packages.

#### **`sudo apt install libavahi-glib1 --reinstall`**

reinstall the "probelatic package"

Comment: Thank you so much, sir. I have got it corrected.

Answer (score 0):

First try reinstalling broken package like prompt says with e.g.

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall libavahi-glib1
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply